# Easily open an image in Gimp from Visual Studio Code Remote Container

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to quickly open an image or photo in Visual Studio Code in Gimp (or any other program)? Most of the projects are utilizing `Remote Containers`.

Currently my workflow is:

1. Open the context menu of the designated file in the explorer
2. Download the file from the container
3. Search and open the file from the system file manager in Gimp
4. Edit the image
5. Save the image
6. Upload and replace the image by drag and dropping it into the same place as the original

Can this workflow optimized? If I have to crop or edit 30 images it takes quite some time like this.